# Quantile transformation with SAS using z-scores?

Tags: sas, gaussian, quantile

Given is a value `quantile_x` (say 42 Euro) which corresponds to the `x`-quantile (say 99%) of a (non-normalized) Gaussian distribution. I am now interested of the value `quantile_y` corresponding to the `y`-quantile (say 95%).

I would love to simply write

```
proc sql;
   create table want as
   select quantile_x
         ,%transform(quantile_x,x,y) as quantile_y
   from have;
quit;
```

For the given example, `%transform()` should actually simply perform the following product

```
quantile_y = quantile_x * 1.645 / 2.326
```

The numbers are the [z-scores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) for 97% quantile and the 99% quantile, respectively. Somehow, I failed to figure out, how I can obtain these two numbers using SAS.

**Edit:** Reading [SAS docu on `probnorm`](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=p0am6dtkvnrb09n132vioa1z6oen.htm&locale=en) it looks like I am after its inverse function since `probnorm(1.96)=0.9750021049`.

#### References

- [SAS-Blog: *Four essential functions for statistical programmers*](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2011/10/19/four-essential-functions-for-statistical-programmers.html)
- [Philippe Jorion's Introduction to Value-at-Risk (VaR)](https://merage.uci.edu/%7Ejorion/oc/case3.html)
- [Wolframalpha z-score for 0.99](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.99%20quantil%20normal%20distribution)
- https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Procedures/Calculate-Z-Score/td-p/501718

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `quantile()` function.

```
data have;
  input x y actual;
  z_x = quantile('NORMAL',x);
  z_y = quantile('NORMAL',y);
  adjusted = actual * z_y / z_x;
cards;
 .99 .95 2.32635
 .99 .95 42
;
```

Results:

```
Obs      x       y      actual      z_x        z_y      adjusted

 1     0.99    0.95     2.3264    2.32635    1.64485      1.6449
 2     0.99    0.95    42.0000    2.32635    1.64485     29.6963
```

Comment: That was much simpler than expected.